# Edits by anonymous users - when are they the "Community" bot?

Tags: support

I ask because I just turned down a minor edit on something that seemed to be done and dusted back in 2010, and the edit came with a comment briefly justifying it. Now I see that the edit has been approved and is claimed by the "Community" user.

The revision in question is [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/18619/revisions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The edit was suggested by an anonymous user, meaning someone visiting the website who was not assigned a user ID (like mine, 7206, or yours 763).

Once the suggestion is approved, the edit is credited (or associated) with whoever suggested it. In the case there is no user to associate it with, the Community user claims ownership, much like the sea claims wreckage.